# Add a border to subtotals with excel vba

Tags: excel, subtotal, vba

I have created a macro that applies subtotals to a worksheet. This is all fine, but I haven't been able to add a border to go right across the subtotal row. Using conditional formatting I have been able to highlight the cell row contains the subtotal function.

Is it possible to add a border and colour the background row for each subtotal row in VBA?

Comment: use the macro recorder to see how to achieve this in VBA

Comment: Not possible as the number of rows for summing up vary as the source data comes from the database.

Comment: you just need to take care of how formatting is done in code. You can then always change the destination to apply the formatting

Answer (score 1):

Use the .Find method to look for whatever function you subtotaled.  For example, if you used COUNT, then look for the word "count".  If you used SUM, then look for the word "total".  Then using the .offset method for the number of cells to the actual total, and use the borders property to add the border.  Example,

```
With Worksheet.Range(c.address).Offset(0,2).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
.Weight=xlMedium
.Color=RGB(255,0,0)
```

Comment: A bit more explanation would be nice -- maybe give a bit of detail on how your methods work. For example, what is `c`? I'd imagine it's the cell in question, but you should explain that. Remember that this site is targeted towards people who have very little experience in coding as well as those with lots.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. For borders use the [Border properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Border_properties.aspx).

Example:

```
With Rows(1).Borders(xlEdgeTop) 'Applies border settings to first row
     .LineStyle = xlContinuous
     .Weight = xlThin
     .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
```

For background color, easiest I think is to use the [ColorIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa199411%28v=office.10%29.aspx) like this:

```
 Rows(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red background on first row
```

Comment: I know about the border object, it is how to get it to work for each subtotal row that is my issue

Comment: So your question is really how to find each subtotal row? I don't know, I would probably loop through the rows and look for the rows that contains a "Total" value or the existence of a formula.